# Con-artist Monty Hall (Generalized)

Tags: combinatorics, stochastic-processes, monty-hall

For:

**d($t_a$)** doors (not already picked or opened at time $t_a$ ),
**$c_{tot}$** cars (initially), 
**p($t_b$)** picks (which depends on **d($t_b$)** == doors available at time of choosing picks),

**o($t_c$)** doors opened (revealing mixtures of cars and/or nothing, thus making accessible cars a 'function' of **o($t_c$)**  =>**c**$(t_{c})$, and

**s($t_d$)** switched (which of course is constrained by accessible doors **d($t_d$)** not already picked or opened).

Where all $t_*$ are in the same Phase of Game play **T**=($t_a,t_b,t_c,t_d$) `time order of updating event; where t_a<t_b<t_c<t_d` , and a set of game play actions **Q**$_n$ = {**$d,p,o,s$**}, 
are related by

**W**$_n$ = Q$_n$**R**$_n$T ==  mapping logical$^{[1]}$ orders of actions onto the time order for a give Phase iteration n .

How would one go about constructing a statistical model for this for some phase n with rules$^{[2]}$? Any help clearing this question for readability, and disambiguate its motifs, is much appreciated.

---

$^{[1]}$ Logical: actions in orders which make sense. Including: no repeat actions during a phase, no run away addition of doors, time order of update says nothing about the amount an action/event is changed (or not change) simply a causal connective.

$^{[2]}$ Rules:

- Game is over when a floor on switching possibilities is met ( this does not require switching ), c = 0, and/or a limit on number of phases is met.

---